Which one is correct ( better ) for ESD Protection? Chassis or Signal Ground
I should to place a PCB in a metallic enclosure having an Ethernet and and USB port. The connectors are placed on dedicated small PCBs mounted on enclosure and connecting to the main PCB by cables.
I should to protect signal pins by using  ESD diodes and comply with IEC6100-4-2. The PCB of connectors have separated planes for signal ground and chassis ground. The chassis ground connects to metallic enclosure by screws.
Should ESD diodes to be grounded to the chassis or signal ground?
Thank you,

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/529454/is-it-better-to-connect-esd-tvs-diodes-to-chassis-ground-or-signal-ground

I have studied in several texts that the esd ground should to be connected to the chassis ground but in schematics the signal ground is connected. please:

Counter question, if you want to protect MCU pin where the USB goes, if chassis ground and MCU ground are  separate, what good is an ESD protection if it does not protect the MCU pin and MCU ground? Also, Ethernet is an isolated interface, at the connector you need to withstand hundreds of volts between connector pins and any ground, so it may be a wrong idea to put ESD protection in reference to any ground on the Ethernet port. You don't say if it is a magjack or connector. You don't say where chassis and signal grounds meet either. The ESD has nowhere to go.

ESD passes through a 1.5kV isolation transformer if there is not path to discharge! I think it is correct that the ESD diode should to protect the MCU finally but in this situation where the chassis ground is closer, it may be preferred to ground it to chassis ground.

The ESD should be connected between the signal line to the signal ground. The reason is because if the signal GND is not the same as chassis ground, then it may damage the signal pin on ESD events.

There are various opinions on this, but I'd suggest the key questions to consider are:

What are you are trying to protect from ESD, (in particular between which points are you trying to limit the voltage difference)?
The impedance of the "diversion"/"clamping" path?
The energy levels.

In the most basic case of a "single ended" input, the desire is normally to limit the voltage difference between the signal wire of an input and the local supply rails (one of which might well be signal ground).
In this case, primary protection is normally achieved by adding diodes or other transient devices between the signal and signal ground/supply wires.
These devices directly clamp the voltage difference between the input and the rest of the device, diverting energy before it can damage the actual input elements.
(A good example of this are the ESD protection diodes on most logic gates.)
This clamping has to be to the signal ground/supply, as the impedance of the chassis path at high frequencies (remembering most ESD is impulsive in nature) is too high for clamping to chassis ground be effective.
In fact where the signal ground is isolated from the chassis ground (for instance where the device uses an isolated supply, and the input is transformer coupled), there is really no option except to use final diode input clamps to the relevant signal rails.
Having said that, there are also circumstances, in particular with transformer coupled differential inputs, where there is a need for additional protection on the "external" side of the transformer.
For instance, on high-speed differential telephony interfaces, it is very common to see diode clamps on the "internal" side of the isolating transformer, but gas discharge tubes and common mode chokes on the "external" side.

(Snip from a design I did for a multi-port DS1 interface card.)
The reason for this split is that the gas discharge tubes have a very high capacity for diverting energy before the transformer (such as the impulse from a near-by lightning strike), whilst the internal clamp diodes provide a harder clamp on the smaller amounts of energy which make it through the transformer, relative to the supply rails.

I think as you. The closer way ( lower impedance ) for discharge is to chassis ground ( connect hardly to metallic enclosure ). But the line which should to be protected is with respect to signal ground ( of the main circuit ). So, I have seen the guides which say connect ESD ground to chassis ground but in schematics connects it to signal ground!

For regular ESD requirements, this should be enough:

Connect chassis to signal ground at some carefully picked location. It might depend on the nature of the product, either do this inside the cabinet if that makes sense, or otherwise elsewhere on the application. You will have to consider avoiding ground loops and chassis currents. And have some sort of plan for where/how shields in cables are connected to chassis.
TVS ("ESD") diodes on the connector grounds could be connected to chassis. However, the chassis and signal ground potentials might differ slightly depending on where they are connected. If you wish to ensure that the TVS somewhat accurately protects within a given voltage range, then it should be grounded to signal ground, possibly bidirectional depending on the signal voltage spec.
The main board needs a TVS to signal ground on the supply pins.
Various other mechanical metal parts present should be grounded to chassis if possible.

For very high EMC requirements you could have an outer TVS towards chassis, then a filter, then an inner TVS towards signal ground. This would be overkill in a commercial application however.
As you can tell, a lot of this is quite application-specific. It might matter if the application is a vehicle, or an industrial installation, or is using chassis as safety ground etc etc.

So I concluded to a solution which uses an ESD diode near to the connector and an ESD diode on the main PCB in applications such this. Discharging to the chassis ground through a ESD diode is beneficial as the interference prevented get distributed in to the sensitive circuits. And the ESD diode on the main board discharges to the signal ground which is connected to the chassis itself guarantee the voltage clamping required.
